# PostgreSQL: How to display comon results from the same table in different columns?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I have a table in Postgres database called FruitMarket and the columns are Fruit, Market, Rate and Vendor.

| Fruit | Market | Rate | Vendor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Sector3 | 50 | alpha |
| Banana | Sector9 | 10 | beta |
| Mango | Sector3 | 60 | gamma |
| Orange | Sector3 | 40 | delta |
| Banana | Sector3 | 15 | epsilon |
| Mango | Sector9 | 70 | omega |
| Orange | Sector9 | 35 | sigma |
| Apple | Sector9 | 45 | kappa |

I want to segregate the Fruit column depending on Market column in such a way that Sector3 is in one column and Sector9 is in a different column in the same table; along with their respective rates and vendors. As shown below:

| Fruit | Market-1 | Rate-1 | Vendor-1 | Market-2 | Rate-2 | Vendor-2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Sector3 | 50 | alpha | Sector9 | 45 | kappa |
| Banana | Sector3 | 15 | epsilon | Sector9 | 10 | beta |
| Mango | Sector3 | 60 | gamma | Sector9 | 70 | omega |
| Orange | Sector3 | 40 | delta | Sector9 | 35 | sigma |

I am guessing it will involve `INNER JOIN` to achieve the second table, but I cannot understand how to give the condition to segregate the Fruit Column using Market Column and display the second table.

The code I tried was

```
SELECT rate as rate1, vendor as vendor1
FROM FruitMarket F1
INNER JOIN FruitMarket F2
ON F1.fruit = F2.fruit
```

Now I am not able to figure out the condition I have to give for Market and how to display all the required columns side by side

Comment: What if one fruit (say, Apple) belongs to N markets and N is very large?

Answer (score 0):

See if it helps you :

```
    SELECT rate as rate1, vendor as vendor1
    FROM FruitMarket F1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM FruitMarket WHERE Market='Sector3') F2
    ON F1.fruit = F2.fruit
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM FruitMarket WHERE Market='Sector2') F3
    ON F1.fruit = F3.fruit
```

The join with a subquery can be used to emulate a table join but with custom results

Comment: Thanks for the approach @mwalter, but let's say there are too many values in Market column, then the condition (SELECT * FROM...) becomes redundant and we have to find a way to select Market values and statement condition to accommodate all the values in Market column

Comment: A SQL generator can be used to make it easier such as :
SELECT 'SELECT rate as rate1, vendor as vendor1
    FROM FruitMarket F1 '
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'INNER JOIN ( SELECT * FROM FruitMarket WHERE Market='||$$'$$||Market||$$'$$||' ) AS '||market||' ON t1.fruit = '||market||'.fruit ' FROM FruitMarket GROUP BY FruitMarket;